# Retain formatting when copying code/XML/JSON from Visual Studio code to MS Word or Outlook

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, ms-word, formatting

Is there a way to copy XML or any other code from VS Code onto MS word or an outlook email and retain the formatting? I tried to use Paste Special option but it doesnt shown the HTML option. I also tried to copy to Notepad++ but MS Word still fails to retain the formatting. Its easy to do in for small 5-6 line code but its cumbersome and waste of time to match formatting for each element.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I saw couple of options on stackoverflow but none work.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio: Copy the code, then in Word use **Home>Paste Special** and choose **Formatted Text (RTF)**.

NotePad++: Check that under the Plugins menu, you have **NppExport**. Choose **Copy all formats to clipboard** from its submenu, then do an ordinary paste in Word.